# Creating Multiple Rectangle Objects at Once (Java)

Tags: java, rectangles, pacman

First off,  thanks for just clicking this :) I'm an amateur student coder, and I'm creating a (horrible) version of Pacman. I'm trying to create rectangles for each of my dots on my 1000x650 applet screen, so I can create an if statement when  Packages hit box touches them, they disappear.

My problem is, I want to create a class so I can create the rectangles easily and have only 1 if statement,  and not one for each dot rectangle (trying to learn to be efficient :P)

If I didn't elaborate enough, I'll be wary to bring edits based on your responses,  and thanks!!!

(Edit 1: Fixed a run on sentence xD)

Comment: Your question is very vague. Pleas show what you have already and ask specific questions when you need specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) statement which repeadly loops untill a condition is met.

This is the general structure:

```
for (counterInitialization; terminatingCondition; incrementLoopsCount) {
    statement(s);
}
```

And this is an example in which the loop continue for as long as the counter `i<n`):

```
int n = 50;
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
//code for creating a rectangle
...
}
```

I suggest you give [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) a read.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fill rectangles on both X and Y (Matrix), you most probably need nested loops.
Let's consider you want to a 5 * 5 rectangle every 100 pixels in the width with a 50 pixels spacing in the height:

```
for(int x = 0;x<1000;x+= 100)
{
     for(int y=0;y<650; y+= 50)
     {
          drawRectangle(x, y, 5, 5); // Considering drawRectangle(x, y, width, height)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will return true when it collides with the dot.

```
Object pacman = new Object();
pacman.xcoord = null;
pacman.ycoord = null;

final int dotsInStage = 50;
// add other properties

int xcoords[] = new int[dotsInStage];
int ycoords[] = new int[dotsInStage];
```

Call this Boolean:

```
public boolean dotCollison (int xcoords[], int ycoords[], Object pacman) {
       loop = 0;
       while (loop <= dotsInStage) {
            if (pacman.xcoord = xcoords[loop] && pacman.ycoord = ycoords[loop]) {
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

To add the rectangles, try:

```
int loop = 0;
while (loop <= dotsInStage) {
   Graphics.drawRectangle (xcoord[loop] , ycoord[loop] , xcoord[loop] + 10 , ycoord[loop] + 10);
}
```

Hope it works and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally comprehending your question. But
Couldn't you just create a 2 d array use a nested for loop

```
For( int I = 0; I<array.length;i++){
For (int j = 0; j <array[0].length;I++){
//fill w/ rectangles
array[I][j]= ;
}}
```